# ping is working but hping (icmp host unreachable) and nmap (host is down) are not working for all websites

Tags: nmap, iptables, ping

I installed hping and nmap tools for the first time. Both tools can't connect to any website including google.com, but ping command works

**Ping**

```
[heman@Main ~]$ ping google.com
PING google.com(bom12s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:810::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from bom12s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:810::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=61.1 ms
64 bytes from bom12s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:810::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=58.9 ms
64 bytes from bom12s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:810::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=57.4 ms
64 bytes from bom12s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:810::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=75.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 57.449/63.118/ 75.012/6.987 ms
```

**HPing**

```
[heman@Main ~]$ sudo hping -I wlan0 google.com
[sudo] password for heman:
HPING google.com (wlan0 142.250.195.46): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
ICMP Network Unreachable from ip=192.168.225.1 name=_gateway
ICMP Network Unreachable from ip=192.168.225.1 name=_gateway
ICMP Network Unreachable from ip=192.168.225.1 name=_gateway
^C
--- google.com hping statistic ---
3 packets tramitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
```

**NMap**

```
[heman@Main ~]$ sudo nmap -sS google.com -e wlan0
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-17 14:57 IST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.23 seconds
```

**My default iptables firewall config in archlinux**

```
[heman@Main /etc/iptables]$ cat /etc/iptables/simple_firewall.rules
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot it any further. Many articles say to use -Pn for nmap but it still doesn't show any open port.

```
[heman@Main /etc/iptables]$ sudo nmap -Pn google.com -e wlan0
[sudo] password for heman:
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-17 15:03 IST
Nmap scan report for google.com (142.250.76.46)
Host is up (0.0037s latency).
Other addresses for google.com (not scanned): 2404:6800:4007:814::200e
rDNS record for 142.250.76.46: maa03s36-in-f14.1e100.net
All 1000 scanned ports on google.com (142.250.76.46) are in ignored states.
Not shown: 998 filtered tcp ports (no-response), 2 filtered tcp ports (net-unreach)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 18.70 seconds
```

I want to be able to successfully ping using hping and scan for open ports using nmap.

I also tested these commands on bing.com. hping and nmap gave same errors while ping was working

Comment: This isn't a security question. This is a pure networking question. hping is telling you that your routing isn't working on your local network. You need to run nmap in verbose mode to fully understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please note that your **ping** is utilising IPv6 while **hping** and **nmap** are trying to send packets via IPv4.
   To begin with troubleshooting, start forcing your ping to use ipv4 instead.
   That should indicate whether it is a IPv4 / IPv6 issue.

```
ping -4
```

2. Don't try with internet sources directly, as you don't know what mechanism and firewalls are in between to maybe block your requests. Try to start
   scanning some local sources in your network first to check the functionality of hping or nmap (e.g. try with your Access-Point etc.)
3. If 2. and 3. are working well. Try to narrow down the problem by scanning different websites (e.g. scanme.nmap.org) to see if google has some security mitigations against simple nmap scans in place.

PS: No full solution just some ideas where to start debugging at.